# Not every number are shown, when their sum of the divisors are good for the conditions

Tags: javascript

I did a bit of coding in javascript and I don't understand the problem...

My goal is to get every divisor of a given number and check if the sum of them is greater than the number itself.

**The divisors should include one, but not the number itself.**

I made 2 functions to separate the code and make it more readable for now.

In the first 12 number, the condition apply only for the number 12 because 1+2+3+4+6=16 which is greater than 12 and it shows it correctly, but when I try the function with the first 20 number, only 18 and 20 are shown, when 12 is clearly good. It disappears when the loop reaches the number 16.

Here is my code:

```js
function getDivisors(n){
    var divisors=new Array();

    for(var x=1;x<n;x++){
      if(n%x==0) divisors.push(x);
    }
    return divisors;
  }


  function getNumbers(n){
    var numbers=new Array(),
    sum=0;

    for(var x=1;x<=n;x++){
      sum=getDivisors(x).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
      if(sum>n) numbers.push(x);
      console.log("Number: "+x+" sum:"+sum);
    }
    return numbers;
  }

  console.log(getNumbers(20));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have `if (sum>x)` instead of `if (sum>n)` inside the for loop in `getNumbers(n)`.